# What is the purpose of the new app.js in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: javascript, laravel

After I have created a fresh Laravel project, I have remarked that now in 5.3, a new app.js generated in the project's directory /js.

Here is the [app.js](https://www.dropbox.com/s/380xoqjiv2ok6u3/app.js?dl=0)

What is the purpose of this pre-generated javascript file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Laravel Documentation:

> By default, the Laravel gulpfile.js file compiles your SASS and the resources/assets/js/app.js file. Within the app.js file you may register your Vue components or, if you prefer a different framework, configure your own JavaScript application. Your compiled JavaScript will typically be placed in the public/js directory.
>
> The app.js file will load the resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js file which bootstraps and configures Vue, Vue Resource, jQuery, and all other JavaScript dependencies. If you have additional JavaScript dependencies to configure, you may do so in this file.

It is also used for writing Vue Components.

Comment: Ok now.
I had never use gulp to compile Js or CSS before in Laravel. And the last time I created a Laravel project, not too long ago, the app.js was not generated. So, I was a bit curious about the origin of this file. Also, in this version of Laravel (5.3), :
By default, fresh Laravel applications contain an Example.vue Vue component located in the resources/assets/js/components directory.

So the app.js file content should be related to the default view component.